# increase download speed for users via nginx

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, vps

Is there a setting with nginx that could be restricting or limiting the download speed of my users? My users are getting around 300kb/s If I use a download accelerator and download a file simultaneously I max out my internet at 1.2 mb/s. My conclusion is that somehow nginx is restricting my download speed. My site does not get heavy traffic, so I don't know why I'm getting such slow speed.

Any ideas what could cause the slow downloads?

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    client_max_body_size 64M;
    access_log  off;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  5;

    server_tokens off;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 1280;
    gzip_buffers 4 8k;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

Comment: Thus the nature of the internet, it's not nginx limiting you.

Comment: Check if sendfile is installed. It must be activated and installed to run.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you've got some weird comparisons going on here.

First: Are your users using download accelerators? If not, then your tests with one are meaningless.

Second: Where are your users in relation to the server?  Where are you in relation to the server?  If your users are significantly further away then you are, this could be causing slow speeds.  If they are on a different ISP than you, your tests just prove it's not an issue with the server nor *your* path to the server.

Third: Do your users experience the slow downloads only sometimes?  For example, if they try during peak times (generally sometime between 6PM-2AM) and have slow speeds, but have significantly increased speeds if they try off-peak this would indicate a capacity issue somewhere along the way.

Fourth: You're on a VPS, when your users report the slow speeds did you test immediately?  It's possible that someone else on the same physical machine as you is doing something very bandwidth/cpu intensive.

Nginx is probably not the cause here.  Did you talk to your provider?  They would really be in a better position to answer your questions then we are.